# Update InstantRails 2 to Ruby 1.8.7 or 1.9.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to update InstantRails, and I did really, really google for any tutorial for it but found none. One site was mentioned to have contained a tutorial but it is not gone http://dwiardiirawan.com/. I know there's this installer available for Windows, but I think one needs to extract a tar file and replace the existing files in the Ruby folder in the InstantRails dir and some fine-tunings for it to work. Would you be kind enough to let me know of something that I can at least try doing?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got 1.8.7 working - I basically downloaded the zipped up file (not the installer one), I extracted it, then I copied & pasted the extracted to overwrite the files and folders in the ruby dir in instantrails. Lastly, I did a gem update --system in the commnand prompt. I haven't tried 1.9.2. One note I must add : I suggest backing up a full copy of your instantrails folder, so if something goes wrong, just delete the original and restore it using this back up.