# how to package ruby with sqlite for running it on windows from an USB Stick

Tags: ruby, windows, sqlite

I want to use rails for a work for school, but the problem is, the school computers have no ruby nor a database installed. I also have no laptop I could just take with me to show it to the teachers. So my question is, whether it is possible and how to package ruby and the sqlite library onto an USB Stick to run my application from this Stick?

Comment: Can the computers at school boot from USB? Then you can go with a Linux Live USB key. Does it have to run on Windows?

Comment: That's a good idea, I will ask my teacher after the hollidays. If I'd be allowed to use a live Linux, I could even use a CD…

Answer (score 1):

Check [InstantRails](http://rubyforge.org/projects/instantrails/) which is a Rails environment on a stick. You could use the Ruby part from that.

Another option is to install Ruby directly on the USB stick and set the `GEM_HOME` environment variable to the drive letter of your USB stick (or, if on Linux / Mac, to the mount point of the stick.) On the school computer, you will have to set the environment variable for it to work.

Comment: Last release seems to be from December 2007 with ruby 1.8.6, I think that's definitely to old…

Comment: You could try to update it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212321/update-instantrails-2-to-ruby-1-8-7-or-1-9-2

Comment: Ok, I now found railsinstaller, which seems to be basically the same, just more up-to-date. I'll try installing that onto an USB Stick and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This could be answered differently, depending on the type of application you're building and what is your definition of *running from USB*

If you used RubyInstaller binary packages (7-zip packages) you can extract on any location, including a USB drive.

Then, using a command prompt, you can add `bin` directory to the `PATH` and install the gems you need for your application to run.

An example if your USB drive is under letter U:

1. Extract Ruby in `U:` (e.g. ruby-1.9.2-p290-i386-mingw32)
2. Open a command prompt
3. Add Ruby to the PATH: `SET PATH=%PATH%;U:\ruby-1.9.2-p290-i386-mingw32\bin`
4. Install your gems and your application (`gem install xxx`)
5. Unmount and unplug your USB drive.

If you want to generate an standalone executable instead, please look at [Ocra](http://ocra.rubyforge.org/)

Comment: I want to use rails, that's written in the first sentence of my questions text. I know rubyinstaller, but my problem is that I need a database, too. So railsinstaller may help, because it brings sqlite with it, I just need to verify I can install railsinstaller to a USB Stick., I will try as soon as I get to a windows pc, probably tomorrow. With running from an USB Stick I mean that I'm not allowed to install anything on the school computers, so I need to put the environment on a stick.

Comment: a "Rails application" doesn't answer. Again, depends on the type of application you're building. Rails can still interconnect with more stuff than just a database. Using RailsInstaller and copy it over your USB drive is the same, except you don't need to do the gem installation process. Ruby on Windows is portable from the go.